# Compress vector graphic by reducing spline complexity

Tags: pdf, compression, spline

My tablet’s note taking application (Boox’ Notes) produces rather large PDFs from hand-written notes; multiple MB for a single page. This seems excessive, and I wonder if I can post-process the files to reduce the size.

I would expect that the strokes can be represented with fewer splines.

Are there established algorithms that find smaller representations of the given shapes (and possibly tools that apply such algorithms to PDF files)?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `cpdf -output-json -output-json-parse-object-streams in.pdf -o out.json` you will get all the page operators, including curves. You can then modify the JSON, and get back to PDF with `cpdf -j out.json -o out.pdf`. That just leaves the actual simplification algorithm to do, for which I would guess there is prior art.

Comment: Thanks! You are the author of `cpdf`, right?

Comment: That's right. I used to write disclaimers in every post mentioning cpdf about how I'm the author, but in the end it seemed to just clog things up, so I stopped.